# NumPy masked operation?

Tags: python, numpy

Say there's a `np.float32` matrix `A` of shape `(N, M)`. Together with `A`, I possess another matrix `B`, of type `np.bool`, of the exact same shape (elements from `A` can be mapped *1:1* to `B`). Example:

```
A =
[
    [0.1, 0.2, 0.3],
    [4.02, 123.4, 534.65],
    [2.32, 22.0, 754.01],
    [5.41, 23.1, 1245.5],
    [6.07, 0.65, 22.12],
]

B = 
[
    [True, False, True],
    [False, False, True],
    [True, True, False],
    [True, True, True],
    [True, False, True],
]
```

Now, I'd like to perform `np.max`, `np.min`, `np.argmax` and `np.argmin` on `axis=1` of `A`, but only considering elements `A[i,j]` for which `B[i,j] == True`. Is it possible to do something like this in NumPy? The `for-loop` version is trivial, but I'm wondering whether I can get some of that juicy NumPy speed.

The result for `A`, `B` and `np.max` (for example) would be:

```
[ 0.3, 534.65, 22.0, 1245.5, 22.12 ]
```

I've avoided `ma` because I've heard that the computation gets very slow and I don't feel like specifying `fill_value` makes sense in this context. I just want the numbers to be ignored.

Also, if it matters at all in my case, `N` ranges in thousands and `M` ranges in units.

Comment: The `where` parameter of `ufunc` may also be useful, e.g. `np.max(A, axis=1, where=B, out=np.full(A.shape[0], -np.inf), initial=-np.inf)`

Comment: @hpaulj Whoa! I must check that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a textbook application for [masked arrays](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/maskedarray.generic.html). But as always there are other ways to do it.

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[ 0.1,    0.2,    0.3],
              [ 4.02, 123.4,  534.65],
              [ 2.32,  22.0,  754.01],
              [ 5.41,  23.1, 1245.5],
              [ 6.07,  0.65,   22.12]])

B = np.array([[ True, False,  True],
              [False, False,  True],
              [ True,  True, False],
              [ True,  True,  True],
              [ True,  False, True]])
```

#### With `nanmax` etc.

You could cast the 'invalid' values to `NaN` (say), then use NumPy's special NaN-ignoring functions:

```
>>> A[~B] = np.nan  # <-- Note this mutates A
>>> np.nanmax(A, axis=1)
array([3.0000e-01, 5.3465e+02, 2.2000e+01, 1.2455e+03, 2.2120e+01])
```

The catch is that, while `np.nanmax`, `np.nanmin`, `np.nanargmax`, and `np.nanargmin` all exist, lots of functions don't have a non-NaN twin, so you might have to come up with something else eventually.

#### With `ma`

It seems weird not to mention masked arrays, which are straightforward. Notice that the mask is (to my mind anyway) 'backwards'. That is, `True` means the value is 'masked' or invalid and will be ignored. Hence having to negate `B` with the tilde. Then you can do what you want with the masked array:

```
>>> X = np.ma.masked_array(A, mask=~B)  # <--- Note the tilde.
>>> np.max(X, axis=1)
masked_array(data=[0.3, 534.65, 22.0, 1245.5, 22.12],
             mask=[False, False, False, False, False],
       fill_value=1e+20)
```

Comment: Fantastic, I haven't heard of the `np.nanfoo` family, otherwise I would not post this. Thank you very much c;